Short story about nostalgia for previous eras of exploration
I'm trying to recall a short story where each chapter has a different character waxing nostalgic about the previous era of exploration of the planet they are on and how they wish they had been able to experience the planet before blah blah blah happened. The next chapter will be someone from that era wishing they had been around for the one before.
The only other specific details I remember are that one chapter was a retired hunter of a native creature that had jewel-like eyes that was hunted to extinction.
I would have read it in the 80s or 90s, so nothing published after 2000 for sure.

Paradise by Mike Resnick

Resnick continues his implicitly African commentaries with this
colorful yet controlled saga of human contact with an alien planet and
its furry, humanoid natives. To the first human arrivals (big-game
hunters, adventurers, freebooters, and the like), planet Peponi's
expansive vistas, natural abundance, and compliant natives seemed like
paradise--as writer-narrator Matthew Breen learns while researching
his anecdotal, nonjudgmental biographies of Peponi's most interesting
figures. Indeed, Breen is so good that Buko Pepon--modern Peponi's
native ruler and accomplished interstellar diplomat--invites Breen to
write his biography. Breen, given virtual carte blanche to pursue his
inquiries, accepts. What he discovers is sobering. Following the
hunter's paradise, a colonial period ensued: the natives were
oppressed and exploited while their planet was raped, subdivided, and
changed out of all recognition by human immigrants.

This goodreads review provides the definitive detail:

In the first part of the book, Matthew Breen is a young student doing
a paper on the "landships" of the planet Peponi - huge, vaguely
elephant-like creatures whose eyes were prized as jewelry. I say
"were" because, at the time this book starts, they have been hunted to
extinction. In pursuit of his paper he performs several interviews
with August Hardwyke, a former big game hunter on Peponi, now dying on
one of the many planets of the Republic, who left when Buko Pepon
became the first native President of an independent Peponi.

While I don't have a direct quote, I do recall that several interviews in the book ended with the interviewee wishing that they had visited the planet earlier, when it must have been paradise.

I kept reading "Peponi" as "Pepperoni" and now I want pizza. Is pizza wrong at 9am?

Pizza - more than just a breakfast food!
